# Storing app info for next load

Tags: uitableview, ipad, ios5

I have an app that I want to use to store different people's data. For example, say you add person A, B, C to a table; then when you tap on them you can add more of their data - phone number, address etc.

I want to be able to store the info for every one of those entries in order to be able to display them when the app starts next time (and when I switch between the different table entries). Currently if I add data to a person's details, if I switch to another person, the data for the first one goes away as I'm not storing in any way.

I don't want to use Core Data as it's only for a low number of entries (about a dozen or so). Can anyone please give me an idea of how I could store each entry so as to pull it at run time (or whenever I tap on an entry that I've added details for already)?

Comment: Have a look at NSUserDefaults, that may suit your needs. Alternatively you could always write the data to a plist or some other file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store each entry in an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`s, which, in turn, can be stored in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: I thought about it but for some reason was reluctant to do it. Is this the simplest and most convenient way to go then?

Comment: Yeah, as all the file handling is done by the system. Only once you have hundreds of records is it a good idea to use your own system, be it a plist or Core Data.